# How to conditionally hide a field in a drupal view?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I have two fields that I want to render but I only want the second one to display when the first one is empty. Short of overriding the field in a template file, can I do this using functionality in the built in views functionality?

Comment: Why you still haven't accepted one of the answers?

Answer (score 16):

For views 3 , drupal 7

- Desired output - Show field1 if field2 is empty.

Add both fields to view in field1, field2 order and select field1 checkbox "exclude from display".

Go to field2 and configure "Show No results behavior". Add field1 replacement pattern e.g [field1] and select "Count the number 0 as empty" , "Hide if empty" and "Hide rewriting if empty".

Now this will produce if else functionality for these two fields.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add the field that you want to show. Select "exclude from display".
2. Add the field that you want to control if you show the previous one. Select "rewrite output". Use the token replacement for showing the previous field. Mark "Hide if empty"
3. There is no three.

PS: Quoted option texts may be not the right ones (I'm looking at a translated site), but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally use the [views_customfield](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) module for this kind of thing. Add a third field to your view that is a php customfield, and exclude your second field from display. You can then write a really quick PHP snippet in the customfield that checks to see if the first field is empty and prints out the second field if it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by the following steps (I've tried it in drupal 7):

1. Add both fields
2. make the first one invisible (exclude from display)
3. in the second field go to no result behavior tab.
4. write the token of the first field (example: [field_name]).

It should work, I hope it will work with you

Answer (score 0):

My solution for showing field_1 for English version and field_2 for translated version:

With use of panels:

1. Make two copies of the view by adding another display to the view.
2. In the original view display you remove or exclude from display `field_2`, in the second display you remove `field_1`.
3. In your panel you add both of your view displays as a panel panes.
4. For the first view display pane add `Visibility rule -> User:language -> English`.
5. For the second view display pane add `Visibility rule -> User:language -> Your_second_language`.

It looks complicated, but it's really simple for people familiar with panels and views.
This solution requires no code changing nor knowledge of theming.

Answer (score -2):

You can kind of massage it into working with contemplate. You could do something like this:

```
    <?php 
if(empty($node->field_foo[0]['view'])){ ?>
<?php print $node->field_bar[0]['view'] ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Using contemplate can be quite dangerous - it's worth looking into separating your theme logic from your database using phptemplate files (x.tpl.php)

Comment: It's not dangerous, it's just hard to maintain. Future devs that work on this project will need to know about this and most devs think to look for code in the code, rather than buried in a view.